# Capturing values from Page Source using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm new to Selenium but have decided to dive right in. Right now I'm using Selenium IDE for test skeletons and the RC for modifying the code in Java.
My current problem is that I want to capture values from the Page Source, specifically Omniture web analytic values. The following code can be found in the page source:

```
s.pageName="Vail:home";
s.prop75="D=v75";
```

Are there any Selenium commands that I can use to capture what values like what **s.pageName** equals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `getAttribute()`

```
String sPageName = driver.findElement(ByLocator).getAttribute("s.pageName");
```

Edit:

I think the `javascriptExecutor()` command would look something like this

```
String sPageName = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return s.getPageName();");
```

You need the keyword `return` to get a value back from `javascriptExecutor()`.
`(String)` should force cast the value returned to a string.

Comment: Awesome! I was reading the selenium command list and saw that one, however wasn't sure what to use as the "By Locator" since it's not a visible element on the page. Or is there another way to locate it?

Comment: @DrewDusang If it isn't visible, you may have to use javascriptExecutor to get the element, or the value from the element.

Comment: Cool  checked out the javascriptExecutor class would the statement look like this:
 `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("s.getPageName();");`

s.getPageName is the function in the javascript giving the value to s.pageName

Comment: @DrewDusang See my edit.  It may not be exactly right, my familiarity with Java (and javascript) is only passingly good.